# Quotient of the linear group by the subgroup of matrices with positive determinant

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G=GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ be the group of invertible $n \times n$ matrices. Let $H$ be the subgroup of the matrices with positive determinant. It is obviously a normal subgroup. What can be said about the quotient $G/H$?

Comment: It's isomorphic to $({\mathbb R} \setminus \{0\})/{\mathbb R}_{> 0}$ (where both groups are multiplicative).

Comment: Shouldn't it be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: In fact, I thought that it would be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, since I consider $f: G/H \to \{-1,1\}$, where $\{-1,1\}$ are the units of $\mathbb{Z}$ with the usual product.

Comment: Yes, my answer could perhaps be simplified further!

Comment: In fact, I thought that it would be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, since I consider $f: G \to \{-1,1\}$, where $\{-1,1\}$ are the units of $\mathbb{Z}$ with the usual product, defined by $A \to \frac{det(A)}{|det(A)|}$, is it correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The map $f: GL_n(\mathbb{R})\to \{-1,1\}$ given by $f(A) = \mathrm{sign}(\det A)$ is a surjective homomorphism with $\ker f = H$, and so by the first isomorphism theorem, $GL_n({\mathbb{R}})/H\cong \{-1,1\}$.