# Is $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$? Yes/NO

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, linear-groups, general-linear-group

$G = GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $H$ is the subgroup of all matrices in $G$ with positive determinant

Is $H$  is a normal subgroup of $G$?

My attempt  : Take G= $ \begin{bmatrix}  2 &0 \\ 0& 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and 
 $H=\begin{bmatrix}  1 &2 \\ 0& 1 \end{bmatrix} $

H  will not  normal subgroup of G

Is its true  ?

Comment: Did you already look for [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2278023/quotient-of-the-linear-group-by-the-subgroup-of-matrices-with-positive-determina)?

Comment: Determinant is preserved by conjugation...

Comment: @DietrichBurde thanks u   i will read now

Comment: $G$ and $H$ are groups, not matrices.

Comment: okss@user3482749.....but  matrics  also  can treat as Group ???

Comment: I added the tags "group-theory", "linear-groups" and "general-linear-group" to your post.  Cheers!

Comment: Step 1: Check the definition of a subgroup. Step 2: Show that $H$ is a subgroup, using an appropriate subgroup criterion. Step 3: Check the definition of a normal subgroup and find an appropriate criterion for normality. Step 4: Verify the said criterion. Looking at your attempt... You are going to have a rough time in the exam. Please talk to your teacher. Getting solutions to homework assignments is not going to help you in the exam, if you don't know that your $H$ and $G$ are not groups. Seriously/frankly/honestly. You have a lot to learn. Hop to it.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  thanks for guidance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $H$ is normal in $G$; for

$h \in H, \; g \in G \tag 1$

we have

$$\begin{align}
\det (g^{-1}hg) &= \det(g^{-1}) \det(h) \det(g)\\
& = \det(h) \det(g^{-1})\det(g) \\
&= \det(h) \det(g^{-1}g) \\
&= \det(h) \det(1_G) \\
&= \det(h) > 0; \tag 2
\end{align}$$

thus,

$g^{-1}hg \in H, \tag 3$

which shows that $H$ is normal.

***Note:*** This demonstration apparently binds for $GL(n, F)$, where $F$ is any field which accomodates a notion of "positivity".  If $F$ is not such a field, we can still assert that the subgroup of elements with $\det(h) = 1$ is normal.  Thanks to Jyrki Lahtonene for pointing this out.

Comment: thanks u   Lewis  sir

Comment: @jasmine:  you are more than welcome my friend.  Glad to help out.  And thanks for the "acceptance"!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen:  thank you for your input  I was hoping a correct answer would pierce the veil of confusion which you correctly pointed out was manifested in the question.

Answer (score 2):

The determinants of similar matrices are the same:  $\operatorname{det}A=\operatorname{det}PBP^{-1}=\operatorname{det}P\cdot
 \operatorname{det}B\cdot\operatorname{det}P^{-1}=\operatorname{det}P\cdot \frac1{\operatorname{det}P}\cdot \operatorname{det}B=\operatorname{det}B$.
This means that $H\triangleleft G$.

Alternatively,  the surjective homomorphism $h:GL_n(\Bbb R)\to\{1,-1\}$ given by the sign of the determinant, has $H$ as kernel.  Thus $H$ has index $2$, hence is normal.